# How to fix width and height on mobile devices for website using HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I currently have my resume uploaded to a website. When I view it on desktop it looks perfect but when I view it on a mobile device the width is shrunk and the height is extended so the text overflows and overall ends up looking terrible. I would ideally like to have the resume show up on the site at the same width:height ratio such that everything is similar to the desktop version. I think if this is to be done the html/css would have to create a fixed width and allow for horizontal and vertical scrolling. I'm not sure how to do this, however, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should use media queries to resolve it.Best to use with rem vm vh and so on.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries